# Iterators - Overloading functions for vector::iterator and array::iterator

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, iterator

I'm trying to overload a certain function so only 
iterators of contiguous containers 
(which are std::vector::iterator ,std::array::iterator ,and built-in arrays iterators == raw pointers) can be a valid argument.

for some reason my functions fail to compile for vector and std::array :

functions:

```
template <class T,size_t N>
void catchIterator(typename std::array<T, N>::iterator it) {
    //do somthing
}

template <class T>
void catchIterator(typename std::vector<T>::iterator it) {
    //do somthing
}
```

example of use :

```
std::array<int, 10> arr;
auto it = arr.begin();
catchIterator(it);

std::vector<int> vec;
auto it0 = vec.begin();
catchIterator(it0);
```

Errors :

```
Error (active)      no instance of overloaded function "catchIterator" matches the argument list
Error (active)      no instance of overloaded function "catchIterator" matches the argument list    
Error   C2783   'void catchIterator(std::array<_Ty,_Size>::iterator)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'   

Error   C2783   'void catchIterator(std::array<_Ty,_Size>::iterator)': could not deduce template argument for 'N'

Error   C2672   'catchIterator': no matching overloaded function found
```

I'm using VC++ with Visual studio 2015 RTM.

The errors are pretty self-explanatory, but I wonder if the
compiler couldn't really deduce T and N from it and it0, after
all, it is part of it/it0 type..

how can make it work?

**Edit:**
I'll go with @ForEveR suggestion and pass the container+iterator/index as arguments instead. 
thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your functions cannot work, since compiler cannot deduce `T` and `N` from iterator, that you send to function.
You can use `std::enable_if`.

```
template <class Iterator>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Iterator, typename std::array<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type, 1>::iterator>::value, void>::type
catchIterator(Iterator it) {
    //do somthing
}

template <class Iterator>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Iterator, typename std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>::iterator>::value, void>::type 
catchIterator(Iterator it) {
    //do somthing
}
```

But there is actually a problem if `vector::iterator` and `array::iterator` are of the same type (on gcc for example) - code will not compile, since compiler will not know which function it should use.

The best way is to just pass container as first argument and iterator as second.

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void catchIterator(const std::array<T, N> &, typename std::array<T, N>::iterator it) {
    //do somthing
}

template <typename T>
void catchIterator(const std::vector<T> &, typename std::vector<T>::iterator) {
    //do somthing
}
```

Comment: the overload for std::vector works great, the overload for std::array compiles only if N is 1, not for every N.. any way to generalize this too?

Comment: @DavidHaim only if you will call `catchIterator` with manual size point.

Comment: @DavidHaim: It should be the case that `std::array<T,1u>::iterator === std::array<T,N>::iterator`.

Comment: @DavidHaim: Yeah... actually it has type `std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,N>`.